# In Some Compilers I Get a "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error

Tags: r, if-statement

Im having a problem in some compilers with running the sample code below. I'm not sure if its a bug in the compiler or if certain compilers need more clear syntax.

```
if (3>2||4>3){
    print("yes")
}
```

While in some compilers I will get "yes", other compilers give me "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed." Does anyone know if I need more clear syntax in my if statement. Thanks!

Comment: There is no compiler in R. R is an interpreted language. Please, specify when you get the error; it's very unlikely that the code you provided can give that error on any R installation.

Comment: As said by @nicola R is an interpreted language. This snippet of code that you wrote runs perfectly.